# Google Cloud Platform Storage JSON API upload breaks audio files..?! How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage

I did manage to upload files to Google storage with GCP resumable upload (json api):
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload

Using jQuery and Plupload http://www.plupload.com

But now it seems that audio files loses their codecs in upload and those won't play or ffmpeg can't probe those. More testing showed that actually .flac files are ok to ffmpeg, but for example .m4a files are not.

I need to get most of the audio files uploaded to google storage and be able to probe those with ffmpeg. And must be able upload big files over 100Mb. That's why I believe JSON API is best or only possible way.

I think I have metadata also added correctly, but now I'm confused how to continue..
Any ideas what could be the problem here?

**EDIT (more info):**

**I had working software:**

- Using regular POST > /temp > Google Cloud Storage Client (php).
- GCP Storage Client uploaded files with perfection.
- Even that I named uploaded files with random unique name like "woeiwehf.tmp", those did work and ffmpeg could probe them fine.

**THEN something happened, I guess uploading like this was limited (or something):**

- What meant that my solution couldn't upload anymore big files, over 32Mb.
- Well that wasn't best solution anyway, so that's okey, that this changed.

**NOW:**

- I have changed software so it uses GCP JSON API upload resumable, and this mainly works
- But I had to change files to look like "woeiwehf.flac" or what ever type is. ".tmp" didn't work anymore.
- For example .flac files work nicely, but .m4a will not.
- I've tested uploading many different ways, and it seems that JSON API upload loses at least codecs and bit rate.

--

I would be very grateful if I could get help how to resolve this.
I guess one solution may could be to fork ffmpeg client and manually set audio codec, but I'm saving that for the last solution.

Comment: Are you trying to access the uploaded files using a browser? If so, what Content-Type are you setting on the metadata for the files that don't play correctly?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I've tested files with browser in GCP storage. When you upload files manually to storage it sets "audio/x-m4a" Content-Type (these work), so I forced this in my software upload. It goes in header "X-Upload-Content-Type". Plupload tries automatically to use "audio/mp4", but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not clear from your response whether you still have a problem. It sounds like you're saying that setting the Content-Type to audio/x-m4a works.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I still have the problem. I meant that if I drag and drop files in browser directly to GCP storage (manually), files work and they give that Content-Type. But when I try to upload through JSON API in my software, files will not work even the Content-Type is the same. So I'm buzzled why that JSON API breaks files.

Comment: if you send email to gs-team@google.com with the specific bucket and object name that has this problem (so you don't have to post those details on the public forum) I can investigate further. If you want me to do that please state that you give me permission to look at the metadata for that specific object. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz thanks man! I have just sent email like you wished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. POST request to Google json API must be exactly as Google docs says

(Example: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload)

Finally I made it work with answer from this question:
[Upload file to Google cloud storage from Google App Engine (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220348/upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-from-google-app-engine-java)

Thanks to user https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371862/renaud-t

```
function uploadFile(fileData, bucket) {
    var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata = {
            'name': fileData.name,
            'mimeType': contentType
        };
        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
                delimiter +
                'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                delimiter +
                'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                '\r\n' +
                base64Data +
                close_delim;

        var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/upload/storage/v1/b/' + bucket + '/o',
            'method': 'POST',
            'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
            },
            'body': multipartRequestBody
        });

        try {
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                if (resp.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
                    //Treat Error
                } else {
                    //Treat Success
                }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            //Treat Error
        }

    };

}
```

## 2. Use Google API Client Library Javascript

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

GAPI Client guide says you should use "then" method, so I changed the above code a bit.

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
  'path': url,
  'method': 'POST',
  'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
  },
  'body': multipartRequestBody
}).then(function(response) {
    // Handle response
  }, function(reason) {
    // Handle error
  }
);
```